# Change all files and folders permissions of a directory to 644/755

Tags: terminal, command-prompt, chmod

How would I change all files to 644 and all folders to 755 using `chmod` from the `linux` command prompt? (Terminal)

Comment: If someone (@animuson) would be so kind to explain me, why this chmod question is off-topic and all others (14,438 results) here aren't...

Comment: Little late, but this one command will also do the accepted answer in one shot: chmod -R a=r,a+X,u+w /your/path

Comment: Good question, doesn't deserve closing.  These should rather be moved to a stackoverflow sub site than closed.

Comment: @hugoderhungrige it means go ask it on a Server site like: `http://superuser.com` :P but this question helped me here, thanks.

Comment: This question comes first in Google, so it should be answered, instead of being closed.

Comment: Short answer: [`chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /foo`](http://superuser.com/q/91935/87805)

Answer (score 411, accepted):

One approach could be using find:

#### for directories

```
find /desired_location -type d -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0755
```

#### for files

```
find /desired_location -type f -print0 | xargs -0 chmod 0644
```

Comment: just for someone else like me, this doesn't work instead try `sudo find /your/location -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;` for files and
`sudo find /your/location -type d -exec chmod 755 {} \;` for directories

Comment: I ran the original solution and it messed up my permissions on files and directories. watch out! the solution on the comment worked, thanks!

Comment: Why (?) it is better tham `chmod -R a=r,u+w,a+X /foo`?

Comment: fails with `unable to execute /bin/chmod: Argument list too long`

Comment: What if I want only the subfolder to be chmod 755 when specifying the desired_location ? Because this also will make the parent folder 755

Comment: I would argue you could combine the two approaches: `sudo chmod -R 755 "/your/location"; sudo find "/your/location" -type f -exec chmod 644 {} \;`. (Not that it makes *that* much of a difference)

Comment: How do I run this command through Python code?

Answer (score 131):

The easiest way is to do:

```
chmod -R u+rwX,go+rX,go-w /path/to/dir
```

which basically means:

to `ch`ange file `mod`es `-R`ecursively by giving:

- `u`ser: `r`ead, `w`rite and e`X`ecute permissions,
- `g`roup and `o`ther users: `r`ead and e`X`ecute permissions, but not `-w`rite permission.

Please note that `X` will make a directory executable, but not a file, unless it's already searchable/executable.

> `+X` - make a directory or file searchable/executable by everyone if it is already searchable/executable by anyone.

Please check `man chmod` for more details.

See also: [How to chmod all directories except files (recursively)?](https://superuser.com/q/91935/87805) at SU

Comment: chmod -R a=r,u+w,a+X /foo

Comment: This answer, while neat, does have a problem: a file that is executable before running the command will be executable afterwards. See the answer of @JohnAllsup for a command that does not have this flaw.

Comment: @mzuther unless this problem is actually feature for you

Answer (score 77):

The shortest one I could come up with is:

```
chmod -R a=r,u+w,a+X /foo
```

which works on GNU/Linux, and I believe on Posix in general (from my reading of: http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/chmod.html).

What this does is:

1. Set file/directory to r__r__r__ (0444)
2. Add w for owner, to get rw_r__r__ (0644)
3. Set execute for all if a directory (0755 for dir, 0644 for file).

Importantly, the step 1 permission clears all execute bits, so step 3 only adds back execute bits for directories (never files). In addition, all three steps happen before a directory is recursed into (so this is not equivalent to e.g.

```
chmod -R a=r /foo
chmod -R u+w /foo
chmod -R a+X /foo
```

since the a=r removes x from directories, so then chmod can't recurse into them.)

Comment: brilliant! helped me a lot

Comment: Way faster than the find-exec method!

Comment: doesn't work on macOS?

Answer (score 51):

On 
https://help.directadmin.com/item.php?id=589 they write:

If you need a quick way to reset your public_html data to 755 for directories and 644 for files, then you can use something like this:

```
cd /home/user/domains/domain.com/public_html
find . -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find . -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

I tested and ... it works!

Comment: Life saver! Thanks for the clean solution to this issue! Worked for me when needing to fix permissions issues for a WordPress install!

Comment: Works well to make the adjustments within a directory.

Answer (score 26):

Easiest for me to remember is two operations:

```
chmod -R 644 dirName
chmod -R +X dirName
```

The +X only affects directories.

Comment: Simplest and safer

Comment: Wow, all these complicated solutions when there is this extremely simple and elegant way to do it! Thank you for sharing.

Answer (score 9):

This worked for me:

```
find /A -type d -exec chmod 0755 {} \;
find /A -type f -exec chmod 0644 {} \;
```

Comment: Be careful: These commands won't handle files or directories with spaces in their names. The commands in the accepted answer will.

Comment: This caveat only applies, if {} isn't surrounded by quotes … thus, there's no reason to play around with print0 and xargs -0, the following suffices:
`find /A -type X -exec chmod Y '{}' \;`

Answer (score 6):

Do both in a single pass with:

```
find -type f ... -o -type d ...
```

As in, find type f OR type d, and do the first ... for files and the second ... for dirs.  Specifically:

```
find -type f -exec chmod --changes 644 {} + -o -type d -exec chmod --changes 755 {} +
```

Leave off the `--changes` if you want it to work silently.