# cakephp call a plugin controller

Tags: php, cakephp, plugins

I'm developing a plugin in cakephp.
I have created a controller inside called `PermissionsController.php` inside `Plugin/Permissions/Controller`

This controller extends another controller: `PermissionManagerAppController.php` in the same directory.

I would like to know how to call a function inside the plugin from another controller like UsersController.php

this is my plugin controller empty now:

```
class PermissionsController extends PermissionManagerAppController {
    public $uses = array('PermissionManager.Permission');

    public function index() {
    }

    public function test($string) {
        echo'<p>TEST: '.$string.'</p>';
    }
}
```

I would like to call action test from another controller.
I have tried this:

```
App::uses('Permissions', 'PermissionsController.Controller');

class UsersController extends AppController {
    public $name = 'Users';
    public $scaffold;

    public function beforeFilter () {
        parent::beforeFilter(); 
        $permissions = new Permissions();
        $permissions->test('test');
       }
}
```

I have also tried

```
App::uses('Permissions', 'Permissions.Controller');
```

return me always this error:

```
Fatal error: Class 'Permissions' not found
```

I have tried:

```
$this->permissions->test('test');
```

And I retrieve this error:

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function test() on a non-object
```

how to solve this?

Comment: Thinking about doing such calls is an indicator for not following the MVC pattern proposed by CakePHP. Depending on the functionality your `test()` method provides, it should probably go into a component or a model, or you should extend the plugin controller.

Comment: Ok but if i only write a vendor file? Because i havn't to write into the database. . Or is better to make only a component? I have used a controller Because i have to make a redirect. . How to do it in component or vendor? @ndm

Comment: I can't recommend you anything without knowing about the exact functionality you are trying to share, you'll have to show some actual code and/or describe this functions purpose. All I can say for now is that redirects can be done from anywhere in your code (though models really shouldn't do that), so you are not limited to a controller, and if the functionality is CakePHP related and doesn't interact with the database, then [**a component**](http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/controllers/components.html#creating-a-component) is _probably_ the way to go.

Comment: Weel, code is a simple function where parameters ar an array. Inside it there are a list of view and user_group and in vase of the actual URL (action passed) I check if that user (in base its group) can access or not at the page, if not redirect to another page. @ndm

Comment: Sounds similar to that what the ACL and auth components do... Judging from the information you provide I'd say a component is the way to go then.

Comment: Perfect thanks for your help, yes is similar ACL, but is more simple to manage access, ASAP I'll publish it on github. @ndm

Comment: You *really* shouldn’t be calling a controller from within another controller. Permissions sounds more like something that would be better packages as a controller component, rather than a controller unto itself.

Comment: great, but you meaning a plugin with a component, or a plugin with component and controller to manage well? If possible answer to my question with an example of the better solution for you tahnks @MartinBean

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Just to build on Thorpe Obazee’s answer and my comment, it’s probably best to build something like permissions management as a controller component as opposed to a controller unto itself. As aforementioned, you really *shouldn’t* be calling controllers from controllers—this goes against the principles of MVC (and in turn CakePHP).

A component can be packaged within a plugin. If your plugin is called `Permissions` and your component is called `Permissions` too, then your directory structure would look like this:

- app

  - Plugin

    - Permissions

      - Controller

        - Component

          - PermissionsComponent.php

When you load your plugin, you can then use this component in your core app’s controller as any other component, just with the plugin syntax:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Permissions.Permissions'
    );
}
```

And your actual component within your plugin would look like this:

```
<?php
App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class PermissionsComponent extends Component {

    public function checkPermission() {
        // code...
    }
}
```

You would then call any component methods as you would a core component method:

```
<?php
class UsersController extends AppController {

    public $components = array(
        'Permissions.Permissions'
    );

    public function beforeFilter() {
        $this->Permissions->checkPermission();
    }
}
```

Hope this helps.

Comment: the only thing missed is how to call checkPermission function, for the rest is a complete answer thanks

Comment: Updated. You would call your plugin component’s methods as you would a core component’s methods.

Comment: Perfect, I think that this answer is very complete for my scope, I haven't used a component because I thinked that a plugin can't be only a component, and for hat I have create a controller and a plugin after..

Comment: No. A plugin can be as little or as complete as you wish, there are no limits either way. I have lots of plugins that are just a view helper or a model behavior or a controller component.

Comment: No problem. All the best with your CakePHP project!

Answer (score 1):

I suggest that you extract the functionality into a component that way functionality can be shared between Controllers.

```
<?php

App::uses('Component', 'Controller');

class TestingComponent extends Component {

    public function sayTesting($email) {
         return '<p>TEST: '.$string.'</p>';
    }
}
```

Update: To add this to a Controller,

```
public $components = array('Testing');
```

Then from a Controller method:

```
public function foobar() {
    $word = $this->Testing->sayTesting();
}
```

Comment: `$this->components = array('Permissions.Permissions')';` assuming your plugin is called `Permissions` and your component is called `Permissions` too.

Comment: Thanks I have seen and it would be a nice solution, you adivse to use controller or model inside the plugin and this component to manage well or is not necessary?

Answer (score 0):

Just to add another note. I also notice that the sub-folders in '/app/Plugin' must have the correct permission (chmod 755). If not, Cakephp will not be able to find/load the plugin.

If you are on ubuntu, just send the command below. Remember to do this for your SUB-FOLDERS too!

```
chmod 755 /app/Plugin/YOUR_PLUGIN_NAME
```

More info about chmod here : [Change all files and folders permissions of a directory to 644/755](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817744/chmod-all-files-to-644-and-all-folders-to-755-of-a-dictory)