# Wordpress on nginx can't create files

Tags: php, wordpress, nginx, hhvm

I'm running Wordpress with HHVM + nginx and wonder, why Wordpress can't create files and isn't allowed to write to directories, even if they are at CHMOD 777.

I'm using W3 Total Cache Plugin and get this message:

[image]

But `wp-content` is at 777 (for testing purposes). Whats wrong with the server configuration?

Comment: Is the permission you given recursive ?

Comment: Yes it is. I used this approach: http://stackoverflow.com/a/18817767/1184904

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Nginx need nginx usergroup permission not apache permission.

Nginx does not have permission to write. So give correct permission.

Here is correct command.

```
chown -R nginx:nginx /var/www/chefgrill.de
```

This will allow nginx to write.

Answer (score 2):

That's did the trick:

```
sudo chmod -R g+w /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html
sudo chgrp www-data /var/www/chefgrill.de/public_html
```