# Laravel does not work on mac

Tags: php, laravel-5

Laravel does not work on after successful installation on mac. When I run the command: `php artisan serve` it is opened at `http://127.0.0.1:8000/` as well as `url` of virtual host. (i.e. laravel.dev). After quitting the command `php artisan serve` if I make any change and refresh the browser, it displays blank page again.

Comment: Odds are some folder(s) don't have permission. My bet is on the cache folder.

Comment: @Andrew thanks it works now.

Comment: I have made whole directory at 777. could you tell me which specific directory should be given permission.

Comment: I honestly can't remember which ones needed permission. But don't do 777, it's highly insecure to do that. 644 for files 755 for directories is the general consensus for such things. See [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18817744/change-all-files-and-folders-permissions-of-a-directory-to-644-755) for a quick and easy way.

Comment: okay thanks, I'll do :)

Answer (score 0):

It works with me when I change port `8000` to another one for example I use port `8080`.

Try the following :

1. In your command line prompt try : `php artisan serve --port=8080`
2. Go to your browser with : `localhost:8080`